# Where did BaseTokenFilterFactory go in Solr 4.0?

Tags: solr

The Solr documentation for creating your own token and character filters says the following.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Specifying_an_Analyzer_in_the_schema

> If you want to use custom CharFilters, Tokenizers or TokenFilters, you'll need to write a very simple factory that subclasses BaseTokenizerFactory or BaseTokenFilterFactory, something like this...

```
public class MyCustomFilterFactory extends BaseTokenFilterFactory {
  public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
    return new MyCustomFilter(input);
  }
}
```

I cannot find the BaseTokenFilterFactory anywhere in the source code for Solr 4.

Here is the org.apache.solr.analysis package from Solr 3.6.1

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_6_1/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/analysis/

And here is the same package for Solr 4.0.0

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_0_0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/analysis/

The documentation looks like it will work for Solr 3.6, but I need to know how to create custom filters using 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With solr 4.0 the `BaseTokenFilterFactory` is now `org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory`, so you can check on [this](http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/).

Comment: Also, it is in the analyzers-common JAR. Not entirely obvious.

Comment: can someone please give a pointer to a jar file which has TokenFilterFactory?

Comment: What about solr 5.4, I need to make my own filter