# ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.tr.ApostropheFilterFactory with Solr 5.5

Tags: java, solr, lucene, classcastexception, solr5

I'm trying to develop my own filter based on https://dzone.com/articles/writing-solr-analysis-filter, but using `TokenFilterFactory` as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13151098/3748908)

I'm using Solr 5.5, and for the development project, I added to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

As for why I'm using version 5.5 of lucene-analyzers-common, the reason is that I first tried with solr-core 5.5, and saw that the classes I need are inside the dependency lucene-analyzers-common, version 5.5.

My class using `TokenFilterFactory` is:

```
public class MyNameFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {
    Map<String, String> args;

    protected MyNameFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
        super(args);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getArgs() {
        return args;
    }

    public void init(Map<String, String> args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    public MyNameFilter create(TokenStream input) {
        return new MyNameFilter(input);
    }
}
```

I package the project as fat jar (otherwise I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory`) and put it under solr-5.5.0/server/lib

But now, when running Solr, I get a different error that I don't know how to solve, because looks to me a lucene's internal issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.tr.ApostropheFilterFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.next(SPIClassIterator.java:158)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.reload(AnalysisSPILoader.java:85)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.<init>(AnalysisSPILoader.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.<init>(AnalysisSPILoader.java:51)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory.<clinit>(TokenFilterFactory.java:31)
```

Any idea how to fix it?
Is there a better approach to develop a custom filter/tokenizer for Solr?

Comment: I am facing the same error with Solr 5.4.1 -- Did you find any solution for this? If yes, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue with Solr 5.1.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCastException when trying to apply custom filter in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148477/classcastexception-when-trying-to-apply-custom-filter-in-solr)